# Setting root log level to a custom not working

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, log4j

My requirement is to define a log level which is in between `INFO` and `DEBUG`. In other words INFO plus something but less than debug. The level needs to be enabled in the root level of log4j.xml file in the tomcat configuration directory. I have done the following :

Set the root log level to custom one **STAT** like :

```
<root>
    <priority value="STAT"/>
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/> 
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    <appender-ref ref="LOGSTASH"/>
</root>
```

Defined a log level class :

```
package com.log4j.logger;

import org.apache.log4j.Level;

/**
 * @author shantha
 *
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class StatLogLevel extends Level {

    public static final int STAT_INT = 15000;

    public static final Level STAT = new StatLogLevel(STAT_INT, "STAT", 6);

    public StatLogLevel(int level, String levelStr, int syslogEquivalent) {
        super(level, levelStr, syslogEquivalent);
    }

    public static Level toLevel(String logArgument) {
        if (logArgument != null && logArgument.toUpperCase().equals("STAT")) {
            return STAT;
        }
        return (Level) toLevel(logArgument);
    }

    public static Level toLevel(int val) {
        if (val == STAT_INT) {
            return STAT;
        }
        return (Level) toLevel(val, Level.DEBUG);
    }

    public static Level toLevel(int val, Level defaultLevel) {
        if (val == STAT_INT) {
            return STAT;
        }
        return Level.toLevel(val, defaultLevel);
    }

    public static Level toLevel(String logArgument, Level defaultLevel) {
        if (logArgument != null && logArgument.toUpperCase().equals("STAT")) {
            return STAT;
        }
        return Level.toLevel(logArgument, defaultLevel);
    }
}
```

In the code, logs are sent using the code :

```
logger.log(StatLogLevel.STAT, "Custom log message");
```

And also added an entry to the log4j.xml :

```
<category name="stats">
    <priority value="STAT" class="com.log4j.logger.StatLogLevel" />
    <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE" />
</category>
```

The result that I am getting is :

```
...
log4j: Level value for root is  [STAT].
log4j: root level set to DEBUG
log4j: Adding appender named [CONSOLE] to category [root].
...
```

and **all the debug messages are printed**.

Appreciate if someone could help on this.

The environment is **java 1.8**, **tomcat 8.5.15** and **log4j-1.2.17.jar**.

Comment: `return (Level) toLevel(val, Level.DEBUG);` looks like you got bit by a typo

Comment: @shinjw Thank you. That's the place where I have missed